# Why didn't the Clone Troopers have their sex drives removed or suppressed?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-clone-wars, clones

[image]
[image]

Based off their art preferences, the Clone Troopers seemed to have an appreciation for the female form.

The *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* episode "The Deserter" features a former Clone Trooper named [Cut Lawquane](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cut_Lawquane) who married and implies that while they aren't supposed to, Clones are capable of reproduction.

> **Rex:** If we fail, then our children and their children could be forced to live under an evil I can't well imagine.
>
> **Cut:** If you were to have children, of course, but that would be against the rules, wouldn't it? Isn't that what somebody programmed you to believe, Captain?
>
> **Rex:** No, Cut. It's simply what I believe. It doesn't matter if it's my children or other people's children.

Such feelings seem like they would be an unnecessary distraction in battle. Given that the Clone Troopers' sole role was to fight for the Republic, why weren't their sex drives removed or suppressed?

Comment: Testosterone promotes aggression as well as sex drive.

Comment: @Buzz Is aggression really required for soldiers who are supposed to mindlessly follow orders?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish, I thought the clone troopers were not supposed to be "mindless".  Isn't that what made them better than droids?

Comment: Also, you could argue that "aggression" can make the clones stronger fighters,  more resilient,  Etc.

Comment: Just wonder if it was the same military mindset that allegedly added Bromide to British soldier's tea during WW1 - to suppress their sex drive

Answer (score 9):

On a Watsonian level: They also didn't have their appreciation for art removed, or their ability to grow facial hair,  their sense of individuality, or any number of other 'extra' features that humans happen to have, but aren't strictly necessary for soldiers. There's no evidence the Kamininoans made an effort to turn them into a fighting force of the type that DS9's Jem'Hadar are, who don't eat, barely sleep, and have no affinity for gambling or sex, so there's no reason to question why this specific aspect would have been removed. The only modifiction that we're certain is that they've been made more obedient:

> LAMA SU: We modified their genetic
>               structure to make them less
>               independent than the original
>               host. As a result they are
>               totally obedient, taking any order
>               without question.

On a Doylist level, the entire point of the clones is to portray them as the opposite of droids. Taking away things that would have us associate them as 'human' would defeat the entire purpose of setting up that dichotomy. Additionally since viewer sympathy is partially earned through similarities to popular depictions of war (Vietnam, WWII, etc) having the clone troopers have the same affinity for pinup art as was popular in those conflicts is part of that.

Comment: appreciation for art, the ability to grow facial hair, their sense of individuality" - The first two have little to no impact on combat, while the third arguable makes them better fighting. In contrast, a sex drive is a distraction that encourages insubordination.

Comment: "A sex drive is a distraction that encourages insubordination". *Any* desire, *any* personal interest, can be a distraction that 'encourages insubordination'. Throughout the show, clone troopers get 'distracted' by their curiosity, by their sympathy for children, by a personal love for biiiig explosions, by any number of things. None of that is deliberately bred out of them. If a soldier is obedient, who cares what they jack off to in their bunk?

Comment: @RogueJedi Grand Admiral Thrawn would disagree about the value of art towards combat ;). I think the overall idea is that these were also left intact; therefore, the fact they left the clone's sex drive intact is not too far fetched either.

Answer (score 1):

**Clone troopers are essentially human males, and for human males sexual drive is huge motivating factor**. Humans as a specie are biologically hard-wired to prioritize safety over almost any other thing. Sexual drive is actually one of few reasons that could compel human male to risk his life. Note that armies use this for centuries in some form or another ( being part of army increases social standing, which in turn increases chances for sex). Making clones asexual would actually **decrease their aggressiveness**, similar to let's say reduced aggressiveness of ox compared to bull.