# Do we know if the clones in Star Wars are made infertile?

Tags: star-wars, clones

The clone army is created from Jango Fett and so the entire army contains his genetic material.

Is it stated anywhere if these troopers were made infertile? I can see issues if they decided to form relationships and have children, especially if on the same planet and you then had a number of individuals all with the same genetic parent/grandparent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the clones sexually reproduce?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178889/can-the-clones-sexually-reproduce)

Comment: I've re-opened this because the proposed duplicate accepts Legends answers and has a Legends-only answer. This looks like it's for canon only, in which case it's not a duplicate. Please confirm, Richard C.

Comment: @Null a non-Legends answer to the previous question would still be an answer, no? Making this one a duplicate.

Comment: I agree with Jenayah, the other has a broader scope but still has accepts canon answers so a dupe.

Comment: @Jenayah If you all want to close it again I won't re-open it as I'm slightly on the fence about it myself, but I'm concerned about the acceptance of a Legends answer on the other question whereas this one would presumably accept a canon-only answer. We don't want users being directed to a Legends answer when/if a canon answer is available.

Comment: @Null if your worry is that there's a canon answer posted for the previous one, but it's not pinned because of an earlier acceptance, then meh. Not our fault if people aren't willing to read past half the page

Comment: We don't need two basically identical questions. Any decent answer to this one could be posted as an answer to that one

Comment: Happy it’s a duplicate thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Clone Wars episode [The Deserter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Deserter), Rex mets a deserted clone trooper who has a wife and children, so apparently the answer is no.

Comment: It's debatable as to whether or not they are adopted or the clones children.

Comment: On top of the adoption possibility, there are also other possibilities: (a) some form of artificial insemination (generating a sperrm from DNA artificially) or (b) given the amount of clone troopers in existence, some may have been produced with a "fault" (not being sterile), and I guess there's also (c) the trooper is unaware that his wife had a lover who got her pregnant.

Comment: It is actually not a debate. Pablo Hidalgo confirmed that they are adopted, which makes perfect sense: have the Clone Wars really been going on long enough for him to have had children that old?